# bypass google verification Samsung S7 Edge no working

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, google-account, google

Neither way on the internet has worked with me so far. I tried to do the internet disconnection process on the software update step I disconnected the internet got the couldn't sign-in and continued however the setup wizard restarted.

I tried connecting the phone to PC while SideSync is opened and also didn't prompt the apps selection like all videos on youtube.

I tried selecting a word and click share nothing happened.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Google has patched all known breaches. Those hacks won't work in android 6.0 (Since July,2 security patch level)

Comment: Any suggestions please? I felt that so is there any other way

Comment: Nope, you have to try may be you'll find out one method. Cause even you get in the phone settings, you won't be able to do nothing.